# How to return a class field if a parameter is true in a list flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SimpleModel {
  
  String title;
  bool isChecked;

  SimpleModel(this.title, this.isChecked);

}

List<SimpleModel> items = [

  SimpleModel ('A', false),
  SimpleModel ('B', false),

];
```

I am using the bool for a checkbox widget and I want show a dialog that confirms the selection which only indicates values are true. But from the method I have tried, I am not getting the result I want because it is only printing out a value of true yet I want to return the title.

```
items.where((element) => element.isChecked == true).toString();
```

Is there a way for me to cross-reference that if a value is true for me to get the title String.

For  clarification, I am trying to use ListView.builder to display the confirmed selection.

Answer (score 0):

items.where((element) => element.isChecked == true).toString(); ---> instead of the cast to toList() and check the title.

```
class SimpleModel {
  String title;
  bool isChecked;
  SimpleModel(this.title, this.isChecked);
}

List<SimpleModel> items = [
  SimpleModel ('A', true),
  SimpleModel ('B', false),
  SimpleModel ('C', true),
  SimpleModel ('D', false),
];

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

var filteredData = items.where((element) => element.isChecked == true).toList();
filteredData.forEach((element) {
  print(element.title);
});
}
```

Output:

```
flutter: A
flutter: C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the result to a list of title's Strings

```
void main() {
      List<SimpleModel> items = [
      SimpleModel ('A', false),
      SimpleModel ('B', false),
      SimpleModel ('C', true),
      SimpleModel ('D', true),
    ];
      
      print(items.where((element) => element.isChecked == true).map((element) => element.title));
       
    }
    
    class SimpleModel {
      
      String title;
      bool isChecked;
    
      SimpleModel(this.title, this.isChecked);
    
    }
```